# Problem obtaing profile pictures from Facebook Graph API

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, social-graph

Have gotten the foundation in place, but now, finding myself wanting to play around with my
application's user's profile pictures; I'm stumped....and have been for quite some hours...

Firstly, my oauth_token / access_token is obtained, using the official (though Alpha ;-)
[Facebook C# SDK](http://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk) and only utilize the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

> *FBapi*.Get("/" + friend.Dictionary["id"].String + "/picture");

leads to an exception due to not returning a JSONObject, and

using the complete http://graph.facebook.com/me/picture is forwarded/translated to the image's URL.

Trying a more direct approach didn't pan out either :

> WebClient wcImg = new WebClient();
>
> wcImg.DownloadFile("/" + friend.Dictionary["id"].String + "/picture", "name_blame.jpg");

Some details are lacking in my question; I beg your pardon, am very tired and will edit later if uproar commences.

Ideas?

---

**Addendum :**
Boy, afflicted by code blindness I was indeed! However, your sensibility gave me what I needed (Zynga, tremble in my canvas ;-).

For sake of curiosity...it appears there's no JSON template(pardon my lack of lingo) available for profile pictures?  Then how do one go about obtaining a fleshed out, Graph API Photo of that profile picture (if available)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The picture in Graph API is a bit special animal. It doesn't return json, it directly forwards to the image. It was made so that you can use this url right in html:

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/<UID>/picture"> - displays avatar
```

Now if you need to know actual picture URL it redirects to there are 2 options:

1. Read redirect headers from that graph URL.
2. Use FQL:

   ```
   select pic_square from user where uid=12345
   ```

There is alot of other info that can be extracted about a user using FQL (including pictures in other sizes).

Answer (score 3):

Also, if You want to show big profile photo, use this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/<UID>/picture?type=large
```

Comment: This isn't working for me to get anything bigger than a large thumbnail.  Do you how to get the source photo for the user's profile pic?

Answer (score 1):

You can get ALL friends' profile pictures (direct Links to the photos), in a single GET request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=[oauth_token]&fields=name,id,picture
```

Then use Json to Decode the string.. and that's all...

NJoy ^_^